# Gradle: Declaring dependency in top level and sub module- which is used?

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

When different `versions` of dependencies are declared in the top-level build.gradle and sub-module build.gradle, which one takes precedence?

For example if in my top level `build.gradle` I had `junit:junit:4.8.2` but in a sub-module had `junit:junit:4.10` ?

Also, what does declaring a dependency in the top level `build.gradle` do? Should all dependencies just be declared in sub-modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having

```
// root build.gradle
subprojects {
    dependencies {
        compile "junit:junit:4.10"
    }
}
```

and

```
// submodule build.gradle
dependencies {
    compile "junit:junit:4.8.2"
}
```

is essentially the same as just having

```
// submodule build.gradle
dependencies {
    compile "junit:junit:4.8.2"
    compile "junit:junit:4.10"
}
```

This means you have two version of junit declared in your submodule. Now Gradle conflict resolution kicks in here. The default resolution for 
dependency conflicts is to choose the newer version. So junit `4.10` will be picked. To change this behaviour you can configure the resolution strategy.